# How to send periodic messages using WebSocket?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, websocket

I am using WebSocket on Tomcat (the actual implementation is Tyrus, the reference implementation of JSR 356). It works great, when I have to handle client messages, and respond to them. However, I would like implement a *push* solution for several of my client-side controls. Actually I need two type of solution:

- pushing out data with a specific interval,
- pushing out system messages, when they are raised.

For the first one, I think [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) can be a solution, I already have a more or less working example, I have issues with cleaning up though. For the second one, I think I would need to have a thread, which would trigger a method in the WebSocket endpoint, but I don't really know how to do this cleanly either. And by clean, I mean that I would like to have running threads only if there are connected sessions to my endpoint.

To summarize my question: *how would you **properly** implement a push message solution using the Java EE WebSocket API?*

ps.: I would prefer a "pure" solution, but Spring is also not unwelcome.

---

#### Current code skeleton

This is how my current solution looks like for the first problem:

```
@ServerEndpoint(...)
public class MyEndPoint {
    // own class, abstracting away session handling
    private static SessionHandler sessionHandler = new SessionHandler();
    private static ScheduledExecutorService timer =
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    private static boolean timerStarted = false;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config) {
        sessionHandler.addSession(session);
        if (!timerStarted) {
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sessionHandler.sendToAllSession("foo");
                }
            }, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            timerStarted = true;
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        sessionHandler.removeSession(session);
        if (0 == sessionHandler.countSessions()) {
            // TODO: cleanup thread properly
            timer.shutdown();
            try {
                while (!timer.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.debug("Timer terminated.");
            }
            timerStarted = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This works more or less, but after a few page reload, it dies with `RejectedExecutionException` and I am not so sure how to handle the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't use any ExecutorService after shutdown();

So after OnClose() method next OnOpen() method will crash.

Just little code for demonstrate:

```
public class TestThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final ScheduledExecutorService timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        boolean timerStarted = false;
        //OnOpen - 1;  - OK
        if (!timerStarted) {
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("foo");
                }
            }, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            timerStarted = true;
        }

        //OnOpen - 2;  - OK
        if (!timerStarted) {
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("foo");
                }
            }, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            timerStarted = true;
        }

        //OnClose - 1  - OK
        timer.shutdown();
        timerStarted = false;

        //OnOpen - 2;  - NOT OK, because after stop you can't use timer,  RejectedExecutionException will thrown
        if (!timerStarted) {
            // will crash at this invocke
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("foo");
                }
            }, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            timerStarted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You may try to use your class also as a web listener http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html
and create timer in methods that executed on startup and destroy of server

```
@WebListener
@ServerEndpoint(...)  
public class MyEndPoint implements ServletContextListener{

    final ScheduledExecutorService timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        timer.scheduleWithFixedDelay(...)
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        timer.shutdown();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I like the idea. Most likely I'll go a different approach though. The Endpoint will only manage the sessions, and a different, periodic service will invoke the send methods of the sessions.